# why am i getting a different number after declaring a variable?

Tags: c

i am new to C programming and i was trying to write a simple program that asks the user to re-arrange the numbers displayed on the screen but i encountered a problem, i would get a different number printed out on the screen instead of the value i assigned to the variable.why am getting a different number? Here is a screenshot of the problem i am having and my code[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZuEo.png):

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
int numOne, numTwo, numThree, ansOne, ansTwo, ansThree;
char name[20];
numOne=34521;

printf("\nWelcome to scrambled numbers Game");
printf("\n Please input your name to get started: ");
scanf("%s", name);
printf("\nRe-arrange this numbers in ascending order %d :", &numOne);
scanf("%d", &ansOne);

if(ansOne==12345)
{
    printf("Congratulations %s you have won the first round", name);
}
else
{
    printf("sorry %s you failed the first round", name);
}

}
```

Comment: If that is C, why added a tag for a different language? And do not use links or images

Comment: `printf()` want values, not pointers to values as `scanf()`. Correct `printf("\nRe-arrange this numbers in ascending order %d :", &numOne);` to `printf("\nRe-arrange this numbers in ascending order %d :", numOne);`

Comment: @Frankie_C i am still having the same problem

Comment: Do you mean that removing the `&` from `numOne` don't print `34521`?

Comment: Sorry @Frankie_C i forgot to build the program before running, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you are printing the adress of the variable numOne instead of numOne it self.

Try removing & operator from numOne in your printf.

Replace this:
    `printf("\nRe-arrange this numbers in ascending order %d :", &numOne);`

By this:
    `printf("\nRe-arrange this numbers in ascending order %d :", numOne);`

Answer (score 1):

`printf` and `scanf` take different kinds of arguments: `printf` needs *values* to be displayed, and `scanf` needs pointer *addresses* to receive input data.

The `&numOne` argument to `printf` causes the program to show the memory address where `numOne` resides instead of the value inside the variable. You want to print `numOne` with no `&` operator.

On the other hand, `&ansOne` is correct for `scanf`.